# How to autostart xbindkeys?

Tags: linux, gnome3, arch-linux, xbindkeys

I use xbindkeys for managing my hotkeys in Gnome 3 but it doesn't have a daemon so I added it to .xinitrc.

```
~$ cat .xinitrc 
ck-launch-session gnome-session
nohup xbindkeys &
```

Strangely, this does not work at all. I still have to manually start xbindkeys every time I boot. What am I doing wrong here?

My system:

```
~$ uname -a
Linux [...] 3.0.28-1-lts #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 16 21:05:30 CEST 2012 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To have xbindkeys running in your Gnome 3 environment you should run **`gnome-session-properties`** and add `xbindkeys` there.
After that just log out and log in again.

(note please, that your `~/.xbindkeysrc` should contain at least 1 command to let xbindkeys demonize)

Anyway, it is not a good idea to run it from `.xinitrc`, you probably should avoid that.
Simply - `.xinitrc` it is a shell script => sequence of commands you are going to run one by one. So your `xbindkeys` will not run until your previous command will not exit (in your example it is `ck-launch-session gnome-session`

Answer (score 4):

In *sh* scripts, including `.xinitrc`, all commands are run serially by default – `nohup xbindkeys` is not considered until `gnome-session` exits. Swapping the lines should work (although `nohup` is useless here).

However, it is better to run `xbindkeys` from GNOME session, rather than `.xinitrc`; otherwise programs started using keybindings *will* break when they attempt to do certain privileged operations (those that are controlled by polkit & ConsoleKit). Add xbindkeys to **`gnome-session-properties`** instead.

Comment: Thank you both very much! Unfortunately I could only mark one answer as accepted so I gave it to the one with less points.